# Texture Mapping Issues with Linked Objects

Tags: texturing, objects, linked-data

The textures I so carefully prepared for various objects shift in position when I link them into a host file. This is for a large architectural project consisting of many modular housing units that are all fairly similar. Textures map beautifully within the blend files but, when I link them into the large ground plane file, they loose all sense of sobriety and appear randomly strewn all over the place!

Comment: Is there any way to upload the .blend file? If it is not too big, you can try sites like Pasteall.org As for your question, this could be caused by several things. It makes troubleshooting much easier if we have access to your .blend, though.